# Push the same card with video attached to more than one user

Tags: python, google-mirror-api

I'm designing a glassware that pushes the same card with a video attached to many users using the following code:

```
mirror_service.timeline().insert(body=videoCard.getCard(),
    media_body=media_video).execute()
```

This means that for pushing the same card to 4 users I need to upload to Google services the same video four times.

Since I think that this is a very ineffective way and causes a lot of overhead I'm asking if there is a workaround to upload the files once and push N number of cards.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with the Mirror API as each cards are scoped to a specific user. Another way to work around this issue would be to use video-streaming instead of pushing the video every time.

With XE9, you can add the video's URL to the `PLAY_VIDEO` menuItem's `payload` property.

Comment: Thanks Alain, this means that by adding the PLAY_VIDEO action the video will be stramed from the given url? Does the video need to be mp4 like the one that i am now attaching?

Comment: The list of supported media formats is documented [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html).

Comment: Ok, i managed to have the item displayed but when trying to play the video i got a 404 white page. The Payload is the following:"menuItems": [
    {
      "action": "PLAY_VIDEO",
      "payload": "http://cds1.yospace.com/access/selector/u/0/1/67791731?f=000067336435&ar=true&d=fb&q=100"
    }
  ]

Comment: It seems like the video player is unable to follow redirect at the moment which leads to this error; if you change the link to the final one, it works: http://cds1.yospace.com/access/d/100/u/0/1/67791731?f=000067336435&amp;fromselector=true&amp;ref=app2-prd-cds1-9326-1379117907103

Comment: Added this issue to the tracker: https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=196